# how to convert long to pair of signed integers

Tags: php, math

Having

```
$t = time();
```

How do I best convert value of $t to pair of *signed* (16bit) integers, for example

```
21232,-16083
```

**EDIT**: Current code isn't pretty, but works:

```
$t = time();
$h = $t >> 16;
$l = $t - ($h << 16);
if ($h > 32767) $h=$h - 65536;
if ($l > 32767) $l=$l - 65536;
echo $h . ',' . $l;
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want ?

Comment: What is wrong with current code?

Comment: Nothing, but with PHP being a C offspring, and me not a C-guy, I was hoping for a C-oneliner.

Comment: Even in C, two assignments cannot be one command (well, except for ugly stuff with the comma-operator etc.). And the if´s are nessecary because of PHP´s weak type system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$thigh = $t >> 16;
$tlow = $t & 0xffff;
if($thigh >= (1<<15)) $thigh -= (1<<16);
if($tlow >= (1<<15)) $low -= (1<<16);
```

(edit:Well, that isn´t more pretty, but that´s how it works)

Comment: why do the costly `%` operation when everything else here is bit operators?

Comment: Yeah, why :) ... changed

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for some sprintf magic but & 0xffff was elegant enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that uses the [pack and unpack functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php):

```
$pair = unpack('slo/shi', pack('l', time())));
// $pair = array ('lo' => -4680, 'hi' => 21232)
```

<sub>Unfortunately this depends on if you are on a big or little endian CPU. Since PHP is typically run on Intel-compatible hardware this is probably not a problem for you.</sub>

Comment: And Dell has a line of servers with ARM cpus. Most PHP installations are still on little  endian architectures.